# Using Database Data in JSON in Android

Tags: android

I have an array which I have hard corded, but I want to use the data from a database instead.

This is a sample of the hard coded version:

```
 private Result[] resultArray = {
                                new Result("id1", "name1"),
                                new Result("id2", "name2"),
                                new Result("id3", "name3")};
```

and this is the SELECT query.

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllUsers(){

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>userArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM user";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            HashMap<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            contactMap.put("Id", cursor.getString(0));
            contactMap.put("name", cursor.getString(1));

            userArrayList.add(contactMap);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return userArrayList;
}
```

How do I use the data from the SELECT query into arrays instead of hard coding the values?

Comment: @Nanoc How do i use the data from the select query instead of harcoding the values? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where is the sense of using `HashMap<String, String>`? Create custom object with two `String` variables and use this object for `ArrayList`.

In your loop just use:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.setId(cursor.getString(0));
myObject.setName(cursor.getString(1));
myArrayList.add(myObject);
```

Also, while working on `Cursor`, remember to **always** close it. You can do it by using `try` / `finally` statement, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of hardcoding you can use like this,

```
contactMap.put("Id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id"));
contactMap.put("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name)));
```

Hope this will help you..